# Prevent KivyMD from drawing a widget several times

Tags: python, widget, kivy, development-environment, kivymd

I am currently building a mobile app with Python and KivyMD. On my application I have an MDExpansionPanel which is called in the on_pre_enter method of the ScreenManager. Naturally this will cause that every time I enter to the same page, the widget will be drawn once again.

Is there a way to delete the previous widget before drawing the new one? I've tried several approaches however I have had no success.

The code for a minimal reproducible example is the following:

Python code:

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel, MDExpansionPanelOneLine
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MyContentAliment(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyContentCasetas(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyContentGasolina(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyContentHosped(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyContentVarios(BoxLayout):
    pass

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass

class TravelManagerWindow(Screen):
    panel_container = ObjectProperty(None)

    # EXPANSION PANEL PARA SOLICITAR GV
    def set_expansion_panel(self):
        # FOOD PANEL
        self.ids.panel_container.add_widget(MDExpansionPanel(icon="food", content=MyContentAliment(),
                                                         panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(text="Alimentacion")))
        # CASETAS PANEL
        self.ids.panel_container.add_widget(MDExpansionPanel(icon="food", content=MyContentCasetas(),
                                                         panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(text="Casetas")))
        # GAS PANEL
        self.ids.panel_container.add_widget(MDExpansionPanel(icon="food", content=MyContentGasolina(),
                                                         panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(text="Gasolina")))
        # HOSPEDAJE PANEL
        self.ids.panel_container.add_widget(MDExpansionPanel(icon="food", content=MyContentHosped(),
                                                         panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(text="Hospedaje")))
        # VARIOS PANEL
        self.ids.panel_container.add_widget(MDExpansionPanel(icon="food", content=MyContentVarios(),
                                                         panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(text="Varios")))

### WINDOW MANAGER ################################

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

ScreenManager().add_widget(LoginWindow(name='login'))
ScreenManager().add_widget(TravelManagerWindow(name='travelManager'))


class reprodExample(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        return WindowManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    reprodExample().run()
```

Kivy code:
:
LoginWindow:
TravelManagerWindow:

```
<LoginWindow>:
    name: 'login'
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Enter'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
            root.manager.current = 'travelManager'

<TravelManagerWindow>:
    name:'travelManager'
    on_pre_enter: root.set_expansion_panel()

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.85}
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
            root.manager.current = 'login'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint:1,0.85
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y":0.37}
        adaptive_height:True
        height: self.minimum_height

        ScrollView:
            adaptive_height:True

            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                cols: 1
                row_default_height: root.height*0.10
                height: self.minimum_height

                BoxLayout:
                    adaptive_height: True
                    orientation: 'horizontal'

                    GridLayout:
                        id: panel_container
                        size_hint_x: 0.6
                        cols: 1
                        adaptive_height: True

                    BoxLayout:
                        size_hint_x: 0.05
                    MDCard:
                        id: resumen_solicitud
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: "250dp", "300dp"
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.9, "center_x": .5}
                        elevation: 0.1

                        MDBoxLayout:
                            orientation: 'vertical'
                            canvas.before:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                            MDLabel:
                                text: 'Monto Total Solicitado'
                                font_style: 'Button'
                                halign: 'center'
                                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15.5**4
                                size_hint_y: 0.2
                            MDSeparator:
                                height: "1dp"
                            MDTextField:
                                id: suma_solic_viaje
                                text: "$ 0.00"
                                bold: True
                                line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                                halign: "center"
                                size_hint_x: 0.8
                                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                            MDSeparator:
                                height: "1dp"
                            BoxLayout:
                                id: expense_graph
                                halign: 'center'

<MyContentAliment>:
    adaptive_height: True
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        adaptive_height:True
        size_hint_x:self.width
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        spacing: dp(10)
        padding_horizontal: dp(10)
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Monto:'
            multiline: 'True'
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
            size_hint_x: 0.15
            font_style: 'Button'
            font_size: 19

        MDTextField:
            id: monto_aliment_viaje
            hint_text: 'Monto a solicitar'
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
            halign: 'left'
            size_hint_x: 0.3
            helper_text: 'Ingresar el monto a solicitar'
            helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
            write_tab: False
            required: True

        MDRaisedButton:
            id: boton_aliment_viaje
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
            text:'Ingresar Gasto'


### CASETAS
<MyContentCasetas>:
    adaptive_height: True
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        adaptive_height:True
        size_hint_x:self.width
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        spacing: dp(10)
        padding_horizontal: dp(10)
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Monto:'
            multiline: 'True'
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
            size_hint_x: 0.15
            font_style: 'Button'
            font_size: 19

        MDTextField:
            id: monto_casetas_viaje
            hint_text: 'Monto a solicitar'
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
            halign: 'left'
            size_hint_x: 0.3
            helper_text: 'Ingresar el monto a solicitar'
            helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
            write_tab: False
            input_filter: 'float'
            required: True


        MDRaisedButton:
            id: boton_casetas_viaje
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
            text:'Ingresar Gasto'

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x: 0.05

### GASOLINA
<MyContentGasolina>:
    adaptive_height: True
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        adaptive_height:True
        size_hint_x:self.width
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        spacing: dp(10)
        padding_horizontal: dp(10)
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Monto:'
            multiline: 'True'
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
            size_hint_x: 0.15
            font_style: 'Button'
            font_size: 19

        MDTextField:
            id: monto_gas_viaje
            hint_text: 'Monto a solicitar'
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
            halign: 'left'
            size_hint_x: 0.3
            helper_text: 'Ingresar el monto a solicitar'
            helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
            write_tab: False
            input_filter: 'float'
            required: True

        MDRaisedButton:
            id: boton_gas_viaje
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
            text:'Ingresar Gasto'

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x: 0.05
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you try `self.ids.panel_container.clear_widgets()` before adding the new ones?

Comment: That did the the trick Arthur. Thanks for your advice.